# Issue with akka in Intellij jav aproject

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have added the following dependency to my java project in IntelliJ.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>
```

`mvn clean install` runs successfully.

But in the IntelliJ editor, the following code doesn't work:

```
public class PointExtractor extends AbstractActor {}
```

Compilation error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'AbstractActor'`

What am I missing here?

Comment: an import (`import akka.actor.AbstractActor;`)?

Comment: Intellij itself asks to press Alt+Enter if it can find the class. But in this case, it doesn't. Manually adding import doesn't solve the issue. I could finally solve it by adding the jar manually to classpath.

Comment: sounds like the intellij isn't in sync with the state of the pom. I don't know how to maven in intellij but I guess you'll just need to find the right refresh button. 
 (or restart). Manually adding jars to the classpath defeats the purpose of a dependency management solution such as maven

Comment: Try this in IntelliJ: File > "Invalidate Caches / Restart"